# Как в PyQt5 в мастере созданном в QWizard передать значение поля registerField с одной страницы мастера на другую?

Tags: python, pyqt5

В PyQt есть класс QWizard для создания многостраничного мастера.

В дочернем (QWizard) классе QWizardPage есть метод

```
registerField(<Свойство>, [, property=None][,changedSignal=0])
```

который, как указано в документации:

> "регистрирует свойство, с помощью которого можно получить доступ к
>   значению компонента с любой страницы мастера"

в приведенном ниже примере (листинг из книги Прохоренок Python 3...)
получаю значение

```
print from page 2 =  None
```

даже на этой же странице

как получить доступ к полю, зарегистрированному с помощью registerField на другой странице мастера?

в методе on_clicked() класса Start все значения выводятся на печать без проблем

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class MyPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 1")
        self.line1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.line1)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)
        self.registerField("line1*", self.line1)


class MyPage2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 2")
        self.setSubTitle("Текст подзаголовка")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 2")
        self.line2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.line2)
        self.setLayout(self.box2)
        self.registerField("line2*", self.line2)
        temp = self.field('line2')
        print('print from page 2 = ', temp)


class MyPage3(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 3")
        self.setSubTitle("Текст подзаголовка")
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 3")
        self.line3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label3)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.line3)
        self.setLayout(self.box3)
        self.registerField("line3*", self.line3)


class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizard.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Мой мастер")
        self.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.ClassicStyle)

        self.page1 = MyPage1()
        self.page2 = MyPage2()
        self.page3 = MyPage3()
        self.idPage1 = self.addPage(self.page1)
        self.idPage2 = self.addPage(self.page2)
        self.idPage3 = self.addPage(self.page3)


class Start():
    @staticmethod
    def on_clicked():
        wizard = MyWizard(window)
        result = wizard.exec()
        if result == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print("Нажата кнопка Finish")
            print(wizard.field("line1"))
            print(wizard.field("line2"))
            print(wizard.field("line3"))
        else:
            print("Нажата кнопка Cancel, кнопка Закрыть или клавиша <Esc>",
                  result)


start = Start()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Класс QWizard")
window.resize(300, 70)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Отобразить диалоговое окно...")
button.clicked.connect(start.on_clicked)

box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(box)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, что бы доступ к field() работал нужно переопределить метод `initializePage()`, согласно документации:

> initializePage(self) — этот метод следует переопределить в классе,
>   наследующем класс QWizardPage, если необходимо производить настройку
>   свойств компонентов на основе данных, введенных на предыдущих
>   страницах. Метод вызывается при нажатии кнопки Next на предыдущей
>   странице, но до отображения следующей страницы.

Рабочий пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWizard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWizardPage


class MyPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 1")
        self.line1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.line1)
        self.setLayout(self.box1)
        self.registerField("line1*", self.line1)


class MyPage2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        # QWizardPage.initializePage(self)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 2")
        self.setSubTitle("Текст подзаголовка")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 2")
        self.line2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.line2)
        self.setLayout(self.box2)
        self.registerField("line2", self.line2)
        self.initializePage()

    def initializePage(self):
        path = self.field("line1")
        print('print from function = ', path)


class MyPage3(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setTitle("Название страницы 3")
        self.setSubTitle("Текст подзаголовка")
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое страницы 3")
        self.line3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label3)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.line3)
        self.setLayout(self.box3)
        self.registerField("line3", self.line3)


class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWizard.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Мой мастер")
        self.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.ClassicStyle)
        self.page1 = MyPage1()
        self.page2 = MyPage2()
        self.page3 = MyPage3()
        self.idPage1 = self.addPage(self.page1)
        self.idPage2 = self.addPage(self.page2)
        self.idPage3 = self.addPage(self.page3)


class Start():
    pass


def on_clicked():
    wizard = MyWizard(window)
    result = wizard.exec()
    field_page_2 = wizard.field("line2")
    if result == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        print("Нажата кнопка Finish")
        print(wizard.field("line1"))
        print(wizard.field("line2"))
        print(wizard.field("line3"))
    else:
        print("Нажата кнопка Cancel, кнопка Закрыть или клавиша <Esc>",
              result)


start = Start()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Класс QWizard")
window.resize(300, 70)

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Отобразить диалоговое окно...")
button.clicked.connect(on_clicked)

box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(button)
window.setLayout(box)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```